# Generate list of all possible unfinished tic-tac-toe positions in Java, considering symmetry

Tags: java, recursion, tic-tac-toe

Given that

- A board is possible if it could occur in a Tic-Tac-Toe game
- An empty board counts as a valid solution
- The board cannot be "finished" (i.e., neither side can have three pieces in a row)
- If two boards differ only by reflection or rotation, they are counted as the same position

How many such positions exist and how can I get an list of them. I tried this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Second {
static ArrayList<int[]> arr = new ArrayList<int[]>();
static int[] board = new int[9];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 19683; ++i){
        int c = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j){
            board[j] = c%3;
            c /= 3;
        }  

        //Check for Xs and Os
        int diff = 0;
        for(int x : board){
            if(x==1){
                diff++;
            }else if(x==2){
                diff--;
            }
        }
        if(diff==0 || diff==1){
            add(board);
        }
    }   
    System.out.println(arr.size());
}

public static void add(int[] board){
    //If the board is won by either side
    if(isCompleted(board)){return;}

    //Get all possible arrangements
    int[] board1 = {board[6],board[7],board[8],   board[3],board[4],board[5],   board[0],board[1],board[2]};
    int[] board2 = {board[2],board[1],board[0],   board[5],board[4],board[3],   board[8],board[7],board[6]};
    int[] board3 = {board[8],board[5],board[2],   board[7],board[4],board[1],   board[6],board[3],board[0]};
    int[] board4 = {board[0],board[3],board[6],   board[1],board[4],board[7],   board[2],board[5],board[8]};
    int[] board5 = {board[2],board[5],board[8],   board[1],board[4],board[7],   board[0],board[3],board[6]};
    int[] board6 = {board[8],board[7],board[6],   board[5],board[4],board[3],   board[2],board[1],board[0]};
    int[] board7 = {board[6],board[3],board[0],   board[7],board[4],board[1],   board[8],board[5],board[2]};

    int[][] boards = {board1, board2, board3, board4, board5, board6, board7};

    //Find the smallest of the 8 possible arrangements
    int[] smallestBoard = board;
    for(int k=0; k<7; k++){
        if(isGreater(boards[k], smallestBoard)){
            smallestBoard = boards[k];
        }
    }

    for(int[] x : arr){
        if(Arrays.equals(x, smallestBoard)){
            return;
        }
    }
    arr.add(smallestBoard);     
}

public static boolean isCompleted(int[] board){
    int piece = 1;

    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[0], board[1], board[2]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[3], board[4], board[5]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[6], board[7], board[8]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[0], board[3], board[6]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[1], board[4], board[7]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[2], board[5], board[8]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[0], board[4], board[8]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[2], board[4], board[6]})){return true;}

    piece = 2;

    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[0], board[1], board[2]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[3], board[4], board[5]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[6], board[7], board[8]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[0], board[3], board[6]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[1], board[4], board[7]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[2], board[5], board[8]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[0], board[4], board[8]})){return true;}
    if(isAll(piece, new int[]{board[2], board[4], board[6]})){return true;}

    return false;
}

public static boolean isGreater(int[] first, int[] second){
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
        if(first[j]>second[j]){return true;}
        if(second[j]>first[j]){return false;}
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isAll(int value, int[] arr){
    for(int x : arr){
        if(x != value){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

This gives a result of 628 possible positions. However, [Michal Forišek's answer to a Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-many-possible-unfinished-Tic-Tac-Toe-positions-are-there-not-including-symmetrical-positions/answer/Michal-Fori%C5%A1ek) gives the answer of 630 positions, including three which I don't have. My program also outputs [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] as a valid positions, which it can't be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466429/generate-a-list-of-all-unique-tic-tac-toe-boards?rq=1 ?

Comment: I have seen this; I'm not sure what's wrong with my code, though. @RC.

Comment: I wonder if you look at the problem as printing out all the base 3 numbers between 0 and 19683. Where 0 corresponds empty square 1 is an O and 2 is a X.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: @Prune I posted my code.

Comment: When you materially change a question, you should retire the original one (by accepting an answer or removing the question) and post the alteration as a new question.  In this case, you've changed the question so much that the "duplicate" claims no longer apply as well, due to the symmetry considerations.

Comment: When I run your code, I get only the **628**, no boards output.  When I add a line to print boards, I do not get the all-2's board.  I do get at least two completed games, which are contrary to your question.  Please retire this properly and open a new question with the customary documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you never backtrack.  You start with an empty board and make a linear-script set of nine moves, filling the board.  There are no more possible moves, so the algorithm terminates, leaving **arr** holding only those nine positions, the squares occupied in order.

To get proper coverage, make **board** a dynamic variable, rather than a static attribute of the class.  Pass it as a parameter to **playThrough**, so that each instance has its own copy.  This isn't a space problem: your call stack has a max depth of 10.

Handling the board dynamically will let the run-time stack manage your backtracking (since each instance maintains its own partial-game state).

I do hope that you're braced for the volume of solutions; 9! isn't large by some standards, but your array of 9! integer arrays of size 9 is something to consider.

Comment: Sorry, I have since changed the question. However, referring to my old question, I _did_ pass board as a parameter to playThrough.

Comment: You passed board, but you maintained it as a static attribute; that killed your backtracking.

Comment: Oh . . . what does static mean? I get an error, "Cannot make static reference to non-static field _board_"

Comment: "Here, let me search that for you ..."
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: I know how to use Google. I still don't understand how this relates to my program. If I change it so that there are no static variables, it still does not work.