# Python list not being passed by value

Tags: python, list

I'm experimenting with creating a tic-tac-toe AI, and one idea was to calculate all possible future board states given a position in order to get the statistically best move. I thought using recursion would be the best way to calculate this, but even before checking all winning positions i got this problem where the board would get changed despite passing a new object in the function.

```
import sys

def calc(board : list, turn : bool):
    game_over = True
    letter = "o" if turn else "x"

    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board)):
            if board[i][j] == "":
                t = list(board)
                t[i][j] = letter
                game_over = False
                calc(list(t), not turn)
    
    if game_over:
        print(board)

def main():
    sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)
    board = [["", "", ""],["", "", ""],["", "", ""]]
    calc(board, True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I get board to not change so I can evaluate ALL possible moves?

Comment: Use board.copy() ?

Comment: @RaniSharim That does the same thing??? Tried it, and it doesn't work.

Comment: ``list(t)`` is only creating a *shallow* copy. Either create a deepcopy or use a shallow board.

Answer (score 0):

That code represent all possible games in final state:

code:

```
import itertools
player = ['O', 'X']
itertools.product(player, repeat = 9)
```

[list comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034364&utm_targetid=dsa-486527602543&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1011523&gclid=Cj0KCQjw-4SLBhCVARIsACrhWLUDTs2qjvcK0priv4fNaNK-Y7p7xuZCEHS1te4x8N0J_vSooFEDkx4aAgI5EALw_wcB):

```
[[i[0:3],i[3:6],i[6:10]] for i in itertools.product(player, repeat = 9)]
```

---

more information:

[Generate a list of all unique Tic Tac Toe boards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466429/generate-a-list-of-all-unique-tic-tac-toe-boards)

---

I suggest [MiniMax Algorithm](https://www.neverstopbuilding.com/blog/minimax) there

Comment: The code in the question only generates boards that are *completely* filled. That's only 512 combinations.

Comment: code is question - generate only this -> [['o', 'x', 'o'], ['x', 'o', 'x'], ['o', 'x', 'o']]